# A function template that takes reference type parameter

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, reference

As I know, there are no arrays of references in C++. For example, a sentence like `int& arr[20];` makes compilation error.

However, in the book *Effective Modern C++*, I saw the following code:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t arraySize(T(&)[N])
{                               ~~~~~~~
    return N;
}
```

I cannot understand how, and why is this parameter declaration allowed.

```
int keyVals[] = { 1, 3, 7, 9, 11, 22, 35 };
int mappedVals[arraySize(keyVals)];
```

And if this sentence is executed, What type is T deduced to? *Effective Modern C++* says T is deduced as a real array type if the function template has a reference type parameter. So the type of T is `int[7]`? Then N's type is `int&[7]`? It's confusing.

Comment: C++ has statements, not sentences. And `T(&)[N]` is a reference *to* an array of `T` having `N` objects.

Comment: That's not an array of references, it's a reference to an array of `T`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the usage of `(&)`, the parameter type is declared as a reference, not an array (or pointer). Then `T(&)[N]` declares a reference to array, which has `N` elements of type `T`.

When you pass `keyVals`, `T` is deduced as the element type of the array i.e. `int`; `N` is deduced as the size of the array i.e. `7`. Note that deducing the size of array is only possible when passing array by reference; otherwise the size won't be reserved because of the array-to-pointer decay.